# Google map display in an iframe working in localhost but not on servers

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an iframe that displays a google map. It has always been working well but it seems like that the new update from google is causing me troubles.

This is how it is displayed in localhost

[image]

And this is what it looks like on both my test and production servers

[image]

My code is :

```
<iframe width="925" height="750" src="https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=4+place+richeb%C3%A9+lille&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&sll=46.22475,2.0517&sspn=25.428258,56.90918&hnear=4+Place+Richeb%C3%A9,+59000+Lille&t=m&z=16&output=embed" frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="no">
```

And we've cleared the browser cache and restarted the service corresponding to the IIS server on the remote server.

Does someone have a clue what's causing this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Has someone observed this kind of problem ?

All the included css files are the same, everything looks the same in the code side, but not in the result :/